# Elasticsearch facets not returned with a ranged query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing documents that look something like this:

```
{
   "title" : "My title",
   "posted_date" : "2014-03-04T04:00:12+00:00",
   "category" : ["cat1", "cat2"],
}
```

Then I am showing listings of these with various sidebar filters for things like category and date(by year, by month). Depending on the options the user selects the resulting query may end up looking something like:

```
{
"query": {
  "range": {
    "posted_date": {
      "gte": "2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
      "lte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
  },
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "and": {
        "filters": [
          {
            "term": {
              "category": "cat1"
            }
          }
        ]
   }}}}}
```

Which seems to work entirely as expected, except when I try to add facets so I can put little numbers (1) next to the dates etc:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "posted_date": {
        "gte": "2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "lte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
      }
    },
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "category": "fiction"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "bymonth": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "posted_date",
        "interval": "month"
      }
    },
    "byyear": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "posted_date",
        "interval": "year"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works only if I don't include the range in the query. If the range is in there I don't get anything returned for facets. It's just not in the result. Even if I change the faceting to be by another term rather than date, I don't get anything.

Is there something incompatible between range queries and facets? Is there something else about the way these queries are structured that makes it not do what I think it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need here [facet_filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html).

```
{
    "facets": {
        "facet1": {
            "terms_stats": {
                "key_field" : "name",
                "value_field": "count"
            },
             "facet_filter": {
                "range": {
                   "filed": {
                      "from": 0,
                      "to": 20
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Your updated query will be look like this:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "and": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "category": "fiction"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "bymonth": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "posted_date",
            "interval": "month"
         },
         "facet_filter": {
            "range": {
               "posted_date": {
                  "gte": "2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "lte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "byyear": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "posted_date",
            "interval": "year"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That won't affect the actual search result though will it? I still need the listing to be constrained to the date range.

Comment: No it will not affect the actual search results, just the facet results.

Comment: I need to have the search results constrained to a date range AND return facets - this seems to be an either-or solution?